# AWS Lambda succeeds outside timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm doing a test where I want my function to fail on timeout.

So i set my timeout to `1 sec`

[image]

My expectation is that it will fail when I invoke the function, however it still succeeds with a duration over the set timeout

```
Duration: 22744.46 ms   Billed Duration: 22745 ms   
Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 74 MB  Init Duration: 639.17 ms
```

Comment: Doesn't sound right. I'd check the Lambda version and associated config. Maybe modify the Lambda to log something new to be 100% sure you're invoking the correct Lambda/version.

Comment: Use  time.sleep() method and add time you want to delay processing your lambda will fail

Answer (score 0):

When timeout, you will see line like this

```
2022-04-01T23:59:10.675Z xxxx Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

next the duration, memory stuffs you post this above

I used following python code, hopes help

```py
import json
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    time.sleep(4)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```